# Why Factory Girl initialized during rake db:schema:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, database-schema, factory-bot

I've upgraded from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1.12 and I got an error message running

```
rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

The error message is an SQL error caused by Factory Girl with missing tables. But why is Factory Girl initialized on `db:schema:load` at all?

It is interesting that if I downgrade to Rails 4.1.11, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behavior of the **FactoryGirl** gem requires it. This is the reason why it gets initialized.

You can alter this behavior by changing the gem definition to:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
```

You will then have to require it in your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```